# Shortcut for save file

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'am just want to know if there will be any shortcut to move focus to selected folder and the text in simple way rather than using `tab` multiple times.

Well this Image will says more,
[image]

I want to select the folder and back to name it after, with keyboard only.
no important reason, just want to know if there any simple way to do it.

Comment: Do you know about `Shift`+`Tab`?

Comment: oh nice, I just know, now I can use `Shift` + `Tab` to go to folder selection and 2x `Tab` to back to filename, so much better than before, thanks

Comment: `Shift` generally reverses keyboard navigation. So when for example `Ctrl`+`Tab` changes tabs in a browser, with additional `Shift` it will go in reverse.